# How to close jitsi a conference room in android?

Tags: android, jitsi

i have a global variable:

```
JitsiMeetActivity session;
```

when i want to join the room i call:

```
session = new JitsiMeetActivity();
session.launch(this, options);
```

which works fine.
but how can i close it programmatically?
if i try to call:

```
try
{
session.leave();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Log.e(“session”, "Failed to properly leave " + e);
}
```

i get:
session: **Failed to properly leave java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetView org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetFragment.getJitsiView()’ on a null object reference**
even though session is not null.

the same happens if i call:

```
session.onDestroy()
```

or

```
session.finish();
```

though `session.onBackPressed()` works fine…

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
Intent hangupBroadcastIntent = BroadcastIntentHelper.buildHangUpIntent();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(hangupBroadcastIntent);
```